# unable to display data from json webservice in listbox of windows phone 7.1 application

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to consume the json webservice from my windows phone application and display the retrieved data on to the listbox. I am able to get the data from the webservice(in the e.result), However, I can not get data in the listbox. 
The following are my xaml code.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" >
            </SolidColorBrush>
            <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/BG@.png" 5F91F5/>-->
        </Grid.Background>
        <ListBox x:Name="carslist" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="3" Height="50">
                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical" Width="420" Height="60">
                            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="420" Height="60">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding cartype}"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding carcode}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

the following is my xaml.cs code.

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string key = "123";
        WebClient getcars = new WebClient();
        getcars.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(getcars_DownloadStringCompleted);
        getcars.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myurl?key=" + "{" + key + "}"));

    }


    void getcars_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
        DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<cars>));
        List<cars> result = obj.ReadObject(stream) as List<cars>;
        carslist.ItemsSource = result;

    }

}

public class cars
{
    public string carcode { get; set; }
    public string cartitle { get; set; }
    public string cartype { get; set; }
    public string carid { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone help me to resolve my issue?...Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know if it will solve your problem, but i would try to add the results to a property and bind this property to your listboxs ItemsSource and so it should work. And i would suggest you to try MVVM in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear why it does not work.
`List<cars> result` is created as local variable inside of getcars_DownloadStringCompleted handler with local scope to that handler, and therefore its immediately garbage collected when this handler is finished.
Thats why you dont see any data.

In order to fix this, create public property on your page for example

```
public ObservableCollection<cars> Results {get;set;}
```

and in the getcars_DownloadStringCompleted handler add your results to that Results collection. Then do this in code:

```
carslist.ItemsSource = this.Results;
```

and it should work.

Also make sure that the items you deserialize from JSon service are valid before adding them Results collection. I would put breakpoint in debugger in the line where you assign items to Results collection and make sure that something is really added there, just to be sure.

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the cars class should also be done if you ask me.

Comment: You probably did not notice `carslist.ItemsSource = result;`, it adds another root and that list won't be garbage collected.